# How can I convert my keys into 'der' format for 'burpsuite' use?

Tags: openssl

I generated my own CA keys as:

```shell
openssl genrsa -out ca.key 2048
openssl req -x509 -new -nodes \
            -key ca.key -subj "/C=GR/L=ATTICA" \
            -days 1825 -out ca.crt
```

How I can convert both:

- `ca.key`
- `ca.crt`

into `der` format?

Answer (score 0):

For the key (file `ca.key`) you can convert it as:

```
openssl rsa -outform der -in ca.key -out ca.key.der
```

For the certificate (file `ca.crt`) you can convert it as:

```
openssl x509 -outform der -in ca.crt -out ca.crt.der
```